# SASS/SCSS object key value loop

Tags: css, loops, sass, compass-sass

Take a look at this example:

```
@include font-face('Entypo', font-files('entypo.woff'));

.icon {
  display: inline;
  font: 400 40px/40px Entypo;
}

.icon-star {
  @extend .icon;

  &:after {
    content: "\2605";
  }
}

.icon-lightning {
  @extend .icon;

  &:after {
    content: "\26A1";
  }
}
```

I want to make things as DRY as possible so I want to know if the following is possible, and if so how?

```
@include font-face('Entypo', font-files('entypo.woff'));

.icon {
  display: inline;
  font: 400 40px/40px Entypo;
}

$icons {
  $star: "\2605";
  $lightning: "\26A1";
}

@each $icon in $icons {
  $key = $icon{key}; // ???
  $value = $icon{value}; // ???

  .icon-#{$key} {
    @extend .icon;

    &:after {
      content: $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Sass does not currently support mappings.  You'll have to live with lists of lists for now.

```
$icons: star "\2605", lightning "\26A1";

@each $icon in $icons {
  $key: nth($icon, 1);
  $value: nth($icon, 2);

  .icon-#{$key} {
    @extend .icon;

    &:after {
      content: $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I hate the documentation of SASS, why can't I find a simple loop like this, thanks anyway, much appreciation.

Comment: If you want something more programatic look at http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/

Comment: The best answer after all other solutions I came across through the whole web

Answer (score 82):

Sass 3.3 (released on 2014/03/07) now allows you to use maps :

```
@include font-face('Entypo', font-files('entypo.woff'));

.icon {
  display: inline;
  font: 400 40px/40px Entypo;
}

$icons: (
  star: "\2605",
  lightning: "\26A1"
);

@each $key, $value in $icons {
  .icon-#{$key} {
    @extend .icon;

    &:after {
      content: $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer for now. Do we have a good way to update or review accepted answer since the accepted one is outdated ?

Comment: You can update the answer to highlight it, and the op still can change the accepted answer if he want.

Comment: This should be the best answer!